# Add A Second Criteria to Array Formula

Tags: excel

I am working with the below formula that I have put together to make a manual task automated. It is an array formula that references a large list of invoices pulled from an accounting software and sorts them according to account numbers.

This formula works perfectly for account numbers that only have one location in them, however some have multiple locations with assigned numbers (i.e. 4040 or 4041). I need this formula to first look at the account number, then look at the store number (this will be entered in a cell near the one containing the account number).

```
{=INDEX('Open Customer Invoices'!$A$2:$N$1000,SMALL(IF('Open Customer Invoices'!$A$2:$N$1000='Company A'!$A$2,ROW('Open Customer Invoices'!$A$2:$N$1000)),ROW('Open Customer Invoices'!1:1))-1,2)}
```

The snippet that says " 'Company A'!$A$2" is where the account number is located.

I attempted to use an "and" function after the "if" to have multiple criteria, but it generates a #NUM issue every time.

In reality, all I am trying to do is make a filter of sorts that is automatic. The reason being is the amount of different accounts I am doing this for.

For example: If account 345678 has three locations: Locations 4, 8, and 9. I want the formula to spit out only the rows for account 345678 location 8.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: AND does not work in array formulas because it is already cyclic calculation. Nest another IF or move to AGGREGATE.

Comment: Concatenate the location and store ids. Assuming the accounts are in one column, you should narrow the if to that column only: `IF('Open Customer Invoices'!$A$2:$A$1000&'Open Customer Invoices'!$B$2:$B$1000='Company A'!$A$2&'Company A'!$B$2, ROW(.....`. That example assumes account in column A, Location in column B

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Worked like a charm!